# How many unit squares can you pack into a rectangle with nearly integer side lengths?

Tags: discrete-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering, puzzle

Earlier today, somebody asked what looks like [a homework problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19443/cubes-to-be-inserted-closed), but admits the following reading which I think is interesting:

> Suppose $a_1,\dots, a_n$ are positive integers, and $\varepsilon$ is a positive real number which you can take to be as small as you like. How many non-overlapping unit hypercubes can you fit into an $n$-dimensional rectangular solid with side lengths $a_i-\varepsilon$?

It's clear that you can't fit $\prod_i a_i$ and that you *can* fit at least $\prod_i (a_i-1)$. A little playing around shows that you can sometimes fit strictly more than $\prod_i (a_i-1)$. For example, here's a packing of three unit squares into a $(2-\varepsilon)\times(3-\varepsilon)$ rectangle:

[image: squares] [(source)](http://i39.tinypic.com/2vwvei0.jpg)

If I haven't made a mistake, you can take $\varepsilon$ to be as large as $1-\frac 23 \sqrt 2$.

- Does anybody know how to find good lower bounds on this number? Using the trick in the above picture, you can effectively get a layer of hypercubes whose length in a given direction is $\sqrt 2 -\frac 12$ instead of $1$. Is there a higher-dimensional version of this trick which does better?
- Does anybody know how to get good upper bounds on this number? In particular, is there an easy way to see that it's never possible to get $\prod_i a_i -1$?

Comment: Just to be pedantic: of course, by "non overlapping" you mean that two (hyper)cubes can intersect at most in a subset of their boundary, right?

Comment: @unknown: Yes, that's what I meant, but it doesn't actually matter. If you come up with a packing where there are intersections on the boundary, then after possibly decreasing your ε, you can modify the packing so that there are no intersections at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a fair bit of literature about efficient packing of squares in squares. See, e.g., Kearney and Shiu, Efficient packing of unit squares in a square, available at http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_9/PDF/v9i1r14.pdf, also Walter Stromquist, Packing 10 or 11 unit squares in a square, available at http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_10/PDF/v10i1r8.pdf

Comment: One source with plenty of pictures is Erich Friedman's website, which includes the following survey: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/papers/squares/squares.html 

Comment: All these references are excellent! In particular, Nagamochi's *Packing Unit Squares in a Rectangle* (available at http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_12/PDF/v12i1r37.pdf) proves that an $(a_1-\varepsilon)\times(a_2-\varepsilon)$ rectangle can hold at most $a_1a_2-2$ unit squares. The results in the references suggest that this is as good an answer as I'm likely to get, so I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @j.c. link to that Erich Friedman survey article is now https://erich-friedman.github.io/papers/squares/squares.html

Answer (score 8):

There is a surprising asymptotic result in 2 dimensions, closely related to your question. See [MR0370368] Erdős, P.; Graham, R. L. On packing squares with equal squares.
J. Combinatorial Theory Ser. A 19 (1975), 119–123.

Comment: Link foe that Erdős-Graham paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316575900990

Answer (score 4):

https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0610.html has some answers for small numbers of squares.